# How to avoid this error defining a \newcommand?

Tags: math-mode, macros, errors, line-breaking

I want to define this macro:

```
\newcommand{stackonetwo}{\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix}}
```

But I think the compiler doesn't like `\\` inside the new command. It returns the error `Missing number, treated as zero`. Why is this error happening, and what is the correct way to circumvent this error and do what I wanna do?

Comment: I haven't tested this, and I don't think it's the cause of the error message, but `stackonetwo` isn't preceded by a backslash, so it isn't a valid control sequence.  If, once you've added the backslash the error still occurs, add a second pair of backslashes around the entire contents of the macro argument.  If that doesn't get rid of the error, then it's something else and more information is needed.

Comment: oops!!! I said to add a second pair of backslashes.  *No!!*  That should be a second pair of *braces*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You say that you get the error missing number, but it is always best to look at the *first* error. If you (or your editor) scroll past an error TeX will try to recover but such recovery often introduces spurious following errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{stackonetwo}{\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix}}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 ...egin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix}}
```

only if you scroll past that do you get

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   a
l.5 ...egin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix}}

?
```

then if you scroll past that TeX gets really confused and you get

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.5 ...egin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix}}

?
```

the initial error is due to the missing `\` in `\stackonetwo` which is causing the letters to "fall out" of the definition and start to be typeset as a paragraph of text before `\begin{document}`

If you fix that error then

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\stackonetwo}{\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix}}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

runs without error and will typeset the matrix as intended when used in math mode.

Comment: This does not work in text mode, and OP has not stated that she exclusively aims to use the command in math mode.

Comment: @Roboticist that is by design. neither does `smallmatrix`. While it's possible to use `\ensuremath` that's really an anti-pattern. TeX commands should almost always be strongly math or strongly text. As this is a shorthand for a `smallmatrix` it's reasonable to assume that math is intended here.

Comment: Simply adding `\ensuremath` won't provide simultaneous math-text compatibility to your answer. Furthermore, "TeX commands should almost always be strongly math or strongly text." is more like a personal opinion, rather than a principle, though I respect your expertise and experience to claim that.

Comment: @Roboticist it's pervasive in the design of all plain tex and latex commands so not just a personal opinion.  see how tex has `\^` (text) and `\hat` (math)  or `\alpha`  (math and nothing for text by default)  and `tabular` for text and `array` for math etc.

Comment: Fairly put. I agree.

Comment: What a long answer to say, *you forgot the backslash*. ;) More importantly, I scrolled up through the compiler output and there was no `Missing \begin{document}` error. Testing it out, this because I defined the newcommand *inside* the begin/end document environment ... [which compiles fine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546004/52612).

Comment: @MikePierce that's why question should always provide a test document, had to make some guesses, I suppose mostly the answer was a comment on the other answer (which did not assume you had forgotten a backslash rather that you wanted a definition form without backslash)  but if your original question had (or if you edit it so it does) show where you used the command I'd change this answer. The main point of the answer was to say to check the first error and if that doesn't apply here the answer isn't much help:-)

Answer (score 5):

Your command has two problems. First, there is no `\` before the given command name. Second, `smallmatrix` envoriment needs to be invoked in math mode. Taken both into account, compilation issue is resolved.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\stackonetwo}{$\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix}$}

\begin{document}    

\stackonetwo

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT 1**: As [Vincent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/201628/vincent) correctly noted, the code above messes with the math-mode usages of the command. Alternatively, the version below lets one use the cammand in both text and math modes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\DefineNamedFunction}[1]{
    \expandafter\providecommand\csname#1\endcsname
    {\ensuremath{\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix}}}
}

\begin{document}    

    \DefineNamedFunction{stackonetwo}

    $\stackonetwo$ 

    \stackonetwo

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT 2**: According to the recommendation of [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) (to address the comment of [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)), the better version of my code may be as follows.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\DefineNamedFunction}[1]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname
    {\ensuremath{\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix}}}%
}

\begin{document}    

    \DefineNamedFunction{stackonetwo}

    $\stackonetwo$ 

    \stackonetwo

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right that ``smallmatrix`` has to be called in math mode, but I'm not sure it's a good idea to add the ``$`` in the command's definition, especially if ``\stackonetwo`` is intended to be used in equations. For example, with this definition, ``\stackonetwo`` cannot be used directly in a display math environment.

Comment: @Vincent: I just added an alternative version.

Comment: What's the advantage in using such a complicated definition when `\newcommand{\stackonetwo}{...}` is much simpler? Besides, `\providecommand` can lead to unexpected results if you say `\DefineNamedFunction{box}{...}`.

Comment: @egreg: I used this method to address the comment of Vincent above, as the edit reflects. Moreover, this answer is specifically composed to address what the OP needs, in which there is no intention to call anything, say, the command name, etc., as box.

Comment: @Roboticist but it gives no guarantee the command has this definition. If some package has defined `\newcommand\stackonetwo[2]{...}`  then your command does nothing and the use in the document gives an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If any package takes the authority for that usage, one would simply change the name of this command to something else (of course not something problematic like the `box` of egreg!).

Comment: @Roboticist so why use `\providecommand` so that the clash is silently ignored, rather than `\newcommand` so that the user is alerted?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I used `\providecommand` as I couldn't manage to achieve what I want to get without it. I'll be happy to see how you would do that to learn even more from you! `:-)`.

Comment: @Roboticist just replace `\providecommand` by `\newcommand` in your definition. (and of course add the two missing `%` at ends of lines, to make egreg happy)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the recommendation. I updated the answer.

Comment: but I think that this doesn't actually answer the question:-) The OP got an error _because a `\  ` was omitted_, so the fix is to add the forgotten backslash not to define a new definition form that does not need it.